# Android FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here is the code. I am trying to make a new child and save the data but the node isn't created on firebase tree. But the code is running successfully. But after updating the sdk, it's not working.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post__feed);
    initialize();
    btn_post_feed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            UploadData();
        }
    });
}

private void initialize() {
    edt_details = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_feed_description);
    spinner_category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.post_feed_spinner);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.post_feed_number);
    btn_post_feed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_feed_btn_post);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MODE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    phn = sharedPreferences.getString("mobno", "A");
    value = sharedPreferences.getInt("value", 0);
}

@Override
public void UploadData() {
    reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("feeds");

    detailsFeeds = new DetailsFeeds();
    detailsFeeds.setCategory(category);
    detailsFeeds.setItemDonateName(quantity);
    detailsFeeds.setPhoneNo(phn);
    detailsFeeds.setItemDonateName(details);
    if (value == 1)
        detailsFeeds.setStatus(true);
    else
        detailsFeeds.setStatus(false);
    reference2 = reference1.child(phn + detailsFeeds.getPostNumber());
    detailsFeeds.increasePostnumber();
    detailsFeeds.setPostNumber(detailsFeeds.getPostNumber());
            reference2.setValue(detailsRegister, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

            if (databaseError == null) {
                setResult(789);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setResult(786);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void DownloadData() {

}

@Override
public void FetchFields() {
    spinner_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomItemSelectedListener());
    details = edt_details.getText().toString();
    quantity = String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress());
}

@Override
public boolean CheckFields() {
    return false;
}

private class CustomItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        category = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

}

[Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ0kO.jpg)

Comment: Do you need firebase auth? Or just realtime database/storage?

Comment: You could also follow the documentation (if you have not done so) to link it... https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

Comment: jst realtime database.

Comment: Okay, then please [edit] your question to include your code and gradle files so that we can see what you're trying to do

Comment: I see you are using firebase-client 2.3.1... Whatever tutorial that you found that is using that is outdated, deprecated, and old. Please find the latest documentation and follow those official guides I linked to

Comment: You also have firebase-auth and crash... So, you lied when you said you only wanted realtime database?